# setFormulas() overwrites values and setValues() overwrites formulas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to copy a range from a template. Then, I need to modify *some* formulas in that range.

If I use `setFormulas()` *all* values in cells that have no formula are erased.

If I use `setValues()` *all* formulas that were not modified are replaced with whatever value was displayed at the time of the `getValues()` call.

This is a huge encumbrance since I would like to modify values and formulas without having to make multiple `getRange()` calls (which are very resource intensive).

Comment: You could call getFormulas() and loop through the array to check if the cell has a formula before setting a formula or a value.

Comment: Consider using a `RangeList` to reduce some of the performance penalty associated with acquiring multiple `Range`s. If all the formulas are equivalent (e.g. the same in R1C1 format or the literal same), then a RangeList will directly support your desires.